# How can I achieve the result with the least complexity?

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm

I have a nested object like this -

```
finalObj = {

"1" : {
    "1" : 0.6,
    "2" : 0.3,
    "3" : 0.1,
    "score" : "a,b"
},
"3" : {
    "2" : 0.4,
    "3" : 0.4,
    "4" : 0.2,
    "score" : "c,d"
},
"4" : {
    "1" : 0.6,
    "4" : 0.4,
    "score" : "e,f"
}
```

}

```
var newObj = {
    "1": [0.6 * (a / b) + 0.6 * (e / f)] / (0.6 + 0.6),
    "2": [0.3 * (a / b) + 0.4 * (c / d)] / (0.6 + 0.4),
    "3": [0.1 * (a / b) + 0.4 * (c / d)] / (0.1 + 0.4),
    "4": [0.2 * (c / d) + 0.4 * (e / f)] / (0.2 + 0.4)
}

var obj = {};
for (let key in finalObj) {
    console.log(key) // "1" , "3" , "4" 
    for (let bey in finalObj[key]) {
        if (bey !== "score") {
            var x = finalObj[key]["score"].split(",")
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(bey)) {
                console.log(x[0] + " if  " + x[1])
                obj[bey] += finalObj[key][bey] * x[0] / x[1]
            }
            else {
                console.log(x[0] + " else " + x[1])

                obj[bey] = finalObj[key][bey] * x[0] / x[1]
            }
        }

    }
}
```

where keys of the outer object refer to `"question_id"` and inner nested objects keys refer to the `"skills_id"` with their weightage, and `"scores"` has two values in a string separated by comma.Example -
`"1", "3", "4"` are question_ids.
Inside question id `"1" : "1", "2", "3"` are skill ids refering to that question.and "score" has "a(marks obtained) , b(total marks)"

I want to return another object with skill id with their normalized scores - newObj

// Where "1", "2", "3", "4" are all the skill ids normalised with the above //used formula.

//How many loops do I need to use to achieve this? Is this a correct way of //putting data in a nested object?

// I am trying something like this as of now -
   // Please help -
   //I am getting the output but the code looks so weird!

Comment: please add the result as well.

Comment: For a,b = 45,50
   c,d = 35,40
  e,f = 5,10

obj = {"1":0.8400000000000001,"2":0.62,"3":0.43999999999999995,"4":0.375}

Comment: you have only the sum of the left side, but the numbers are not divided by the sum of `0.6 + 0.6` for the first value. the first result should be `0.7`

Comment: yeah correct. handled. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would collect the left and right values for summing in advance and the build the result of the division in a last step.

For taking the values, I suggest to usen an appropriate object with the corresponding keys.

```js
var data = { 1: { 1: 0.6, 2: 0.3, 3: 0.1, score: "a,b" }, 3: { 2: 0.4, 3: 0.4, 4: 0.2, score: "c,d" }, 4: { 1: 0.6, 4: 0.4, score: "e,f" } },
    values = { a: 45, b: 50, c: 35, d: 40, e: 5, f: 10 },
    collection = {},
    div = (a, b) => a / b,
    result;

Object
    .entries(data)
    .forEach(([k, o]) => Object
        .entries(o)
        .filter(([l]) => l !== 'score')
        .forEach(([l, v]) => {
            collection[l] = collection[l] || { left: 0, right: 0 };
            collection[l].left += v * o.score.split(',').map(k => values[k]).reduce(div);
            collection[l].right += v;
        })
    );

result = Object.assign(...Object
    .entries(collection)
    .map(([k, o]) => ({ [k]: o.left / o.right }))
);

console.log(result);
console.log(collection);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```